Merge 2 ~/.kube/config into one
Cluster information:
Kubernetes version:
Client Version: v1.30.0
Server Version: v1.28.2
Host OS: SUSE Server 15 SP4
CNI and version: calico
CRI and version: containerd://1.7.3

Description
Im trying to merge  ~/.kube/config_1 and ~/.kube/config_2 into one ~/.kube/config_2 and this is how it looks now:
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ###
    server: https://k8s.some1.net:443
  name: some1
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ###
    server: https://k8s.some2.net:443
  name: some2
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: some2
    user: kubernetes-admin-1
  name: kubernetes-admin@some1
- context:
    cluster: some2
    user: kubernetes-admin-2
  name: kubernetes-admin@some2
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin-1
  user:
    client-certificate-data: ###
    client-key-data: ###
- name: kubernetes-admin-2
  user:
    client-certificate-data: ###
    client-key-data: ###

Problem:
When I run eg. kubectl get nodes I get error:
$ kubectl get node
E0521 12:53:29.547657  321565 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0521 12:53:29.548296  321565 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0521 12:53:29.549911  321565 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0521 12:53:29.550502  321565 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0521 12:53:29.552173  321565 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

UPDATE
By following hint from @larsks, I edited .kube/config as follow:
Indeed, it was missing current-context key.
My current working .kube/config looks as this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ###
    server: https://k8s.some1.net:443
  name: some1
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ###
    server: https://k8s.some2.net:443
  name: some2
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: some2
    user: kubernetes-admin-1
  name: kubernetes-admin@some1
- context:
    cluster: some2
    user: kubernetes-admin-2
  name: kubernetes-admin@some2
current-context: "kubernetes-admin@some2"
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin-1
  user:
    client-certificate-data: ###
    client-key-data: ###
- name: kubernetes-admin-2
  user:
    client-certificate-data: ###
    client-key-data: ###

NOW, by default Im getting resources of cluster 2 (kubernetes-admin@some2).
By running kubectl config use-context kubernetes-admin@some1, im getting access to resources of cluster 1 (kubernetes-admin@some1).
To go back to cluster 2, run kubectl config use-context kubernetes-admin@some2.

Try running kubectl config use-context kubernetes-admin@some1 (or kubernetes-admin@some2) first. It looks like your merged kubeconfig file is missing the current-context key.

Yes it does missing current-context. Otherwise if i keep it, I will ghet the following error   
kubectl get nodes 
error: error loading config file "/home/lab/.kube/config": yaml: line 16: did not find expected key

Sounds like you had it set to an invalid value. It must be set to the name of a context in your kubeconfig file. Try what I suggested in my previous comment. I think we've identified the problem.

Yes, that works now (i would sware I tried that before but I Was getting the error u see in my comment). Anyway, thanks @larsks

You don't need to manually merge Kubernetes config files. You can merge them using the KUBECONFIG environment variable:
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config_1:~/.kube/config_2

This way, when you run kubectl, everything defined in these config files will be available. You can see the result of the merge with:
kubectl config view

To make this change permanent, add the above line to your  ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc file.  Make sure to reload your shell configuration or restart your terminal session for the changes to take effect.
For more details read Merging kubeconfig files from the official documentation.

That doesnt work for me AND i guess it still requires to run kubectl config use-context.
If i do that I get: 0603 11:37:34.336608  705095 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
